# whose regex is faster? python or perl

Tags: python, regex, perl

I saw in the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

that python use non-recursive implementation as grep and sed while perl one uses the simple cursive impl. does this indicate that python's regex performance is faster than perl's?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not a direct answer because the answer to the Python v. Perl regex question seems to be "it depends".

If you are concerned about regex speed, there are a few things you should look into.  One is to use plain search and replace, where possible, instead of regex.

The other is to use [Google's re2 module](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), which has good wrappers in a number of languages. In my experience, re2 is about 60% faster than the built-in re module in Python, and where it particularly shines is with "pathological" regex expressions that could take much longer than you'd expect using the built-in module.  All this and more is explained [here](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), in the paper by Russ Cox, who developed re2.

In Python, I use and can vouch for [pyre2](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2), a wrapper for re2, which acts as a drop-in replacement for re. A CPAN search shows that [re::engine::RE2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?re%3a%3aengine%3a%3aRE2) appears to serve the same function in Perl.

Comment: in general case, can we compare the efficiency between the cursive and non-cursive implementations?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your q, but one of the [original papers](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html) includes a few benchmarks of the RE2 vs. PCRE implementations. As you can see for most of the tests, the PCRE implementation is the same or slightly faster for small text size, but as the total text size increases, re2 blows it out of the water.

Comment: A simple Perl `s///` is faster than the equivalent Perl code. This is because the `s///` engine is written in C.

Comment: PCRE is not Perl's regex engine. It's a separate library designed to mimic Perl's useful extensions to the standard regex syntax/features.

Comment: My experience testing a very simple search of /usr/dict/words in both Perl and Python is that Python is 100x slower in CPU time (on this one test only).  Perl version 0.03sec user CPU: ``cat /usr/share/dict/words | time perl -ne '/^and/ && print'  | head -5`` .... Python version uses 3.0sec user CPU: ``cat /usr/share/dict/words | time py -fx 're.match(r"^and", x)' | head -5`` (requires the excellent Pythonpy for 'py' command: https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy).  Python's slowness is due to regexes not startup/regex compilation overhead, as the CPU time scales with size of file.

Comment: Haven't used ``pyre2`` yet, but https://github.com/agent8/pyre2 seems worth a look - though none of the pyre2 forks seem very actively maintained.

Answer (score 6):

This guy has a good post

http://stuffivelearned.org/doku.php?id=programming:general:phpvspythonvsperl

Comment: I should point out that the author of the linked post has a serious flaw in his methodology: once Python compiles a regular expression from a string, it caches the compiled regex. The reason Perl appears so slow in the uncompiled case compared to Python is that Python is doing a cache lookup, not a recompile.

Comment: Hum, he has numbers for compiled and non-complied python. Are you saying the non-complied numbers are flawed?

Comment: I'm talking about the compilation of the regular expression (which happens after execution), not the Python code. In the "pre-compiled" version, he compiles the expressions at the start; in the "non-compiled" version, he passes a string as the regular expression. My claim was that passing a string as a regex adds the overhead of a cache lookup, but does not actually re-compile the regular expression, as it seems to in Perl. The "interpolated string loop" test in Perl and "no pre-compiled" test in Python aren't really doing the same task.

Comment: ah, I see there is actually a discussion about that at the bottom of the post, maybe he will redo the test and post the results.

Comment: There's a flag to tell the Perl reg exp engine that the expression does not change. Might be what you want..